# Column Increment not working in Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

When someone visit the details page, i want to add 1 value to the column views and register users.
But it is not working

**Controller**

```
function detail($seo_url, $id) {
    $this->load->model('business_model');
    
    if($_SESSION['user_auth']!=''){
        
        $data = array('views'=> 'views+1','register_users' => 'register_users+1');
        $this->business_model->updateBusiness_stats($id,$data);
    }else{
        $data = array('views'=> 'views+1', 'nonregister_users' => 'nonregister_users+1');
        $this->business_model->updateBusiness_stats($id,$data);
    }
}
```

**Model**

```
function updateBusiness_stats($id,$arr) {
        $this->db->where(array('id' => $id, 'domain_id' => config_item('domain_id')));
        $this->db->set($arr);
        $result = $this->db->update($this->_table_name);
        //echo $this->db->last_query();
        return $result;
    }
```

**Query after prints**

```
UPDATE `business` SET `views` = 'views+1', `register_users` = 'register_users+1' WHERE `id` = '826' AND `domain_id` = '23'
```

**Can someone guide me where i am doing mistake?**

Comment: [The manual about updating data using the query builder](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#updating-data) explains how to add a raw statement into the query (tldr; the method `set()` supports a third argument for this). If it doesn't work when passing in an array, you can iterate the array and add them one by one.